# PHP: Hybridauth redirects to HTTPS page

Tags: php, authentication, facebook-login, hybridauth, google-plus-signin

I have the following problem with HybridAuth:

Lets say I started on the page "http://dev.EXAMPLE.COM/login.php".

I now have the following script:

```
        require_once('hybridauth/config.php');
        require_once( "hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php" );
        $hybridauth = new Hybrid_Auth( $config );
        $adapter = $hybridauth->authenticate( $provider);
        $user_profile = $adapter->getUserProfile();
```

It should just redirect to Facebook/Google/Twitter, then go to the `HybridAuth` index.php, where the process should be finished and then redirected back to the page where I started ("http://dev.EXAMPLE.COM/login.php").

The only problem I have now is, that it redirects to "https://..." instead of "http://...", which doesn't work because I don't have a ssl certificate on my dev server so the browser will just show an error.

How can I fix this error? How do I get `HybridAuth` to redirect to the right, http://..., page?

config.php:

```
<?php
    $config = array(
    "base_url" => "http://dev.XYZ.COM/hybridauth/",
    "providers" => array (

        "Google" => array (
            "enabled" => true,
            "keys"    => array ( "id" => "XYZ", "secret" => "XYZ" ),
        ),

        "Facebook" => array (
            "enabled" => true,
            "keys"    => array ( "id" => "XYZ", "secret" => "XYZ" ),
        ),
    ),
    "debug_mode" => false,
    "debug_file" => "",
);
```

P.S.: I also tried adding `"trustForwarded" => 1` to the config, but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

For the future world:
You can manually set the redirect url via

```
hybridauth->authenticate($PROVIDER, array("hauth_return_to" => "http://REDIRECT.URL"));
```